# Built-in SD card reader not working

Tags: 12.04

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on a Advent 7109b/Uniwill L51II9.

Tried both 1 & 2 GB M2 cards (in both M2 duo & M2 adaptors) and I know the cards work.

The card reader is a 4-in-1 Media Card Reader: SD, MMC, MS, MSPro

lspci returns the following

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 3 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 02)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
06:04.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): O2 Micro, Inc. Firewire (IEEE 1394) (rev 02)
06:04.2 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Integrated MMC/SD Controller (rev 01)
06:04.3 Mass storage controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Integrated MS/xD Controller (rev 01)
06:05.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
```

I know this is similar to other posts, but I cannot see one that has been confirmed as solved (forgive me if this is not accurate!)

Thanks in advance

```
*-generic
            description: SD Host controller
            product: Integrated MMC/SD Controller
            vendor: O2 Micro, Inc.
            physical id: 4.2
            bus info: pci@0000:06:04.2
            version: 01
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm cap_list
            configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=32
            resources: irq:18 memory:b0200800-b02008ff
*-storage UNCLAIMED
            description: Mass storage controller
            product: Integrated MS/xD Controller
            vendor: O2 Micro, Inc.
            physical id: 4.3
            bus info: pci@0000:06:04.3
            version: 01
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: storage pm cap_list
            configuration: latency=32
            resources: memory:f0202000-f0202fff
```

Looking at the results of 'sudo lshw' above, I am wondering if the problem is with the 'UNCLAIMED' Mass Storage controller.........

From looking on the internet it would seem like this has been an ongoing problem for previous versions of Ubuntu, so I'm hoping there is an easy fix out there, I just need to find it.

Again any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to reformat, for clarity.  Add 4 spaces before each line of **lspci** response.

Comment: @david6 Thanks for info David - I was wondering how to sort that. I hope its easier to read now

Comment: OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years and this question is about 12.04 (EOL) and has no answers. VTC as `not reproducible`.